# Offset Handling in jquery.rss

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I want to include a RSS-feed on my website, where I load 5 entries at first and later load more as the user scrolls down the page (due to page response times).

I am using jquery.rss (https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss) for the RSS-feed and waypoints to fire the RSS reload when the user reached the page end (http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

I thought I could just use jquery.rss offset (limit:5, offsetStart: 5) to load entry 5-10 for example but I seem to not use it correctly.

```
$("#rss-styled").rss("http://www.recruiter.com/feed/career.xml", {
limit: 5,
offsetStart: 5,
layoutTemplate: '<dl class="dl-horizontal">{entries}</dl>',
entryTemplate: '<dt><a href="{url}">{title}</a></dt><dd>{shortBodyPlain}   [{author}@{date}]</dd>'
}).show();
```

Here is my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/AFHfn/

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

There appears to be an issue in jquery-rss itself, I have raised the issue here with the developer but not heard anything as of yet

https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss/issues