# Display posts from blog offset by 3 with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, rss

I am using jquery-rss to display the latest posts on a web page. What I want is to display 3 posts, but not the three latest, the three after that. So if I were to pull through the top 6 it would display the last 3.

Post 1 - Not displayed
Post 2 - Not displayed
Post 3 - Not displayed
Post 4
Post 5
Post 6

How would I approach this with javascript or jQuery?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
    $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://news.bearingnet.net/feed/", {

      layoutTemplate: "<div class='feed-container'>{entries}</div>",
      entryTemplate: "<div class='rssEntry'><p class='padding-top'>{teaserImage}<a href='{url}' target='_blank'>{title}</a><br /> {date} <br />{shortBodyPlain}...<div class='text-right'></p><p><a href='{url}' target='_blank' class='btn main-bg'>Read more</a></p></div></div>",
    })
  })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be sarcastic - but it clearly is an advantage if you just READ the letters of the docs.

```
$("#rss-feeds").rss(
  "http://feeds.feedburner.com/premiumpixels",
  {
    // how many entries do you want?
    // default: 4
    // valid values: any integer
    limit: 10,

    // want to offset results being displayed?
    // default: false
    // valid values: any integer
    offsetStart: 3, // offset start point
    offsetEnd: false, // offset end point

    // will request the API via https
    // default: false
    // valid values: false, true
    ssl: true,
.....
```

Right from the documentation page..

Look for `offsetStart`. That should do it. The whole process: googleing "jquery-rss" looking for your answer, took me around 15 seconds. This has nothing to do with showing off.. I'm just trying to open some eyes.

***Update/Edit:***

OK, so.. having a look at the discussion below in the comments, I'll just throw in another solution or better **workaround** which is kind of awkward, and only because the other options don't seem to work.

You can simply hide the first three RSS posts with these css-rules:

```
.feed-container:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
.feed-container:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: none;
}
.feed-container:nth-of-type(3) {
    display: none;
}
```

This workaround simply hides the first three posts. It is neither elegant, nor the right way to do it - but it should work.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work which is why I want to do it with javascript

Comment: What does not work ? If an error occurs, then your browser console should give you an error, describing the problem. What happens when you do use the standard code? jQuery is based on Javascript, so.. you  are already using Javascript.

Comment: It does not offset the display, it still pulls through the latest posts. I have not found anything in jQuery to help me, which is why I wanted to use true javascript and come here for help.

Comment: OK, for the future: please provide as much information and details as possible. Are you loading jquery? Which version? Where do you load it (header or footer)? Just a few questions that come to my mind right away.. Here is another post on SO - which I have just found by goooooooogling...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248203/offset-handling-in-jquery-rss - This guy's offset is not working either. So.. best idea would be to contact the developers straight ahead. Last Git commit is 7 days ago, so they are active.

Comment: Ok ta for that. I left them a request a few days ago and not had anything back yet. 

Loading in the head, 1.11.3

Is there no way to programme this in the meantime?

Comment: I have just googled, and there are lot's of tools to get an rss feed up and working.. your special desire to skip the first three posts is not covered by anybody because it is a rare feature, that nobody needs - your turn as a programmer to stand out ;)

Comment: Such a rare feature that it was included as standard in the jQuery?